# Make the last date of one record the first date in the next record in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that takes one parameter and returns data. The parameter is a username, and the return data is each of the servers that a users profile resided on at specific times. So it shows the username, server, begin date and end date. For most users, the return is 1 record. But for some users there will be multiple records. An example of the return:

```
UserName    Server  BeginDate   EndDate
smithp      server2 7/10/2021   7/17/2021
smithp      server1 6/19/2021   7/3/2021
```

There is a gap between server1 end date and server2 begin date. I would like to update the server2 begin date to the server1 end date. So basically, the last day on one server is the first day on the next. Is this possible within a stored procedure? My current code is below.

```
alter procedure GetUserHistory
( @UserName varchar(50) )
as
begin
set nocount on;
;with cte AS
(
select UserName, Server, min(Datestamp) as BeginDate, max(Datestamp) as EndDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
(
    partition by UserName
    ORDER BY max(Datestamp) DESC
) As RowNum
FROM UserData where Datestamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE()) And UserName = @UserName
GROUP BY UserName, Server
)
select * FROM cte WHERE rowNum > 1
END
```

Comment: Check out the LAG function - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That was what I needed. Thank you.